# Is there a name for this type of subset?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm coloring a graph, and have multiple colors to use. The colors themselves don't matter, just that they are distinct from one another. So, for example, with 2 nodes, and colors A, and B, I could paint:

> AA, AB

Notice how BB is equivalent to AA (both nodes are painted with the same color), and BA is equivalent to AB (both nodes have distinct colors).

With 3 nodes, we have these options

> AAA; AAB, ABA, BAA; ABC

So, all nodes with the same color, or two nodes of a color and the third distinct, or all nodes distinct. And with 4 nodes,

> AAAA; AAAB, AABA, ABAA, BAAA; AABB, ABAB, ABBA; AABC, ABAC, ABCA, BCAA, BAAC, BACA; ABCD

I'm looking for a way to generate this sub-set, but I don't even know what it's called. Is there a name for this sub-set generation method?

Comment: It sounds like you are wanting to partition a set into unlabeled parts. Look up "bell number"

Comment: Sounds like "equivalence classes."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing the [Bell Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).

The bell number $B_n$ counts the number of ways of partitioning a set of $n$ elements into any number of nonempty unlabeled subsets.  Here, you are partitioning the positions within your string or equivalently the nodes in your graph (*your graph having labeled nodes*) into different color classes.

Equivalently, $B_n$ counts the number of equivalence relations for an $n$ element set.

The sequence beginning from $B_0$ is $1,1,2,5,15,52,\dots$

More information can be found in the link above.  Of particular note is the relation between Bell Numbers and [Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) which instead of counting the number of unlabeled partitions of $n$ elements into specifically $k$ non-empty parts.

If instead of the *number* of such items appearing in each of your lists, you are more interested in the *items themselves*, these can be viewed as the equivalence relations on a set with $n$ elements.  If you are interested in a way of generating the list of these, you might consider doing so recursively.  Having generated the list of equivalence relations on $n$ elements, to generate the list of equivalence relations on $n+1$ elements just decide what to do with the $n+1$'st element.  It either goes into one of the already existing parts (*one of the already existing color classes*) or put it into its own new part (*give it a new color*).